# How to know the image dimensions in pixels to fit all screens

Tags: react-native, image, expo

I'm working on a react native application in a company and my manager asked me what is the best image size in pexels to upload from API (dashboard) to fit the View in the application ?

And I'm using percentage units not numbers: (width: '80%', height: '50%') I don't know what is the best sized of images to fit or the aspect ratio of the image and react native is unitless!

What should we add 'Hint' for the client in the dashboard when he upload any image ?
Or how could I know the best image dimensions to fit all screens ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In our organisation, we usually follow the following convensions to make an image fully responsive.

1. Get the dimentions of the image using: const {width, height} = Image.resolveAssetSource('path-to-your-image');
2. Get the ratio factor of width and height by using: const ratioFactor = height/width;
3. Whenever you set the width of your screen by 'n' digit, set the height to 'n*ratioFactor'
4. In this ways the image can never be stretched or compressed. It will be fully responsive according to it's dimensions.
5. Preferably use image with standard dimentions as 1024 x 768 pixels.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by "n" digit ?

Comment: By "n" digit I mean, let's say you want to set the width of the image to 1200px or wp(12) then the height will be 1200* ratioFactor or wp(12)* ratioFactor. What will it do, basically it will reserve the dimensions by reserving their aspect ratio. So the image will be responsive, neither stretch nor compressed. Try it and lemme know if any confusion

Comment: I got your idea but what if the image dimensions is bigger than the phone screen how to handle it and reserve the ratioFactor ?

I'm setting the width to be 80% of the screen and the height like what you said

Comment: Worked perfectly with me thank you so much dude.

Now I can add any image whatever the size and show it all is it is.

Answer (score 0):

In case the app target both iOS and Android, there is a multitude of devices with various resolutions and pixel densities from high-end iPads to low-end androids devices with smaller resolutions.

The General rule of thumb is to find the average image size which will not pixelated (look blurry) on the high-end devices but does not have a large download size in case some users will have slow internet.

You should start with 1024 x 768 pixels which is a standard dimension for iPad

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `resizeMode` prop of react native image. With `resizeMode` you can manage to render image based on available space in screen.

Check it here : https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#resizemode